# Render multiple GLKViewControllers at a time

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

I have a simple GLKViewcontroller subclass that renders a texture when told.  This works great on its own, exactly what I need it to do.  However, for some reason, when I am trying to use it in a scene in which I have 6 copies of the same view controller at a time (set up as container views pointing to the same view) it doesn't work.  I have a load and show texture method to select which texture to draw from a map of loaded textures. It would seem that only the last view i loaded the textures into draws them properly, the remainder show up as black squares.

Here's a screenshot of my storyboard:

[image]

Here's my load and draw code:

```
-(void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.view.opaque = NO;
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    //sprite render:
    if ( self.showTexture )
    {
        if ( firstDraw )
        {
            self.imageShowTime = [ATAppDelegate getCurrentTime];
            firstDraw = NO;
        }
        self.effect.texture2d0.name = selectedTexture.name;
        self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;
        self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = self.modelMatrix;

        [self.effect prepareToDraw];

        long offset = (long)&_quad;

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);

        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(TexturedVertex, geometryVertex)));
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(TexturedVertex, textureVertex)));

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    }
    else
    {
        firstDraw = YES;
    }
}

-(void)loadTextures:(NSArray *)textureNames
{
    if ( textures == nil )
    {
        textures = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    [textures removeAllObjects];

    NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                              GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft,
                              nil];
    NSError * error;

    for ( NSString *texName in textureNames )
    {

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:texName ofType:nil];
        GLKTextureInfo *newTex = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:path options:options error:&error];
        if ( newTex == nil || error != nil )
        {
            NSLog(@"Error loading file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            return ;
        }

        NSLog(@"Loaded texture: %@ for name: %@", newTex, texName);

        CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(newTex.width, newTex.height);

        NSDictionary *texInfo = @{@"texture" : newTex, @"contentSize" : [NSValue valueWithCGSize:contentSize]};

        textures[texName] = texInfo;
    }
}

-(void)showTexture:(NSString *)texture
{
    NSDictionary *texInfo = textures[texture];

    if ( texInfo == nil )
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: no texture info found for texture name :%@ in %@", texture, textures);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Showing texture: %@", texInfo);
    }

    selectedTexture = texInfo[@"texture"];
    curContentSize = [texInfo[@"contentSize"] CGSizeValue];
}
```

Comment: This architecture is... weird, and possibly problematic in more ways than you're running into just yet. What are you trying to use this collection of `GLKViewController`s *for*?

Comment: To quickly render textures in multiple specific locations on the screen

Comment: Why not use one view and one OpenGL context, then? You can draw multiple textured quads in different locations with multiple bind and draw calls, updating the model matrix between calls to reposition.

Comment: @rickster Because I need the layout to resize for different device sizes.  I mean I could theoretically manage it in code, but thats kind of what autolayout and constraints are supposed to (and do) handle

Comment: I'm glad @MaticOblak's answer is working for you, but... Propagating a layout architecture into every layer of the rendering stack sort of abuses the lower layers. You're duplicating client-side work in your multiple `GLKView`s, GL-library work in your context switching, and  window server work in having separate CA layers. If you're set on using UIKit for layout, you might consider using it *only* for layout, and then doing all your GL rendering in one view/context: i.e. use a bunch of invisible views for UI layout, then read their frames when you need to decide where to draw in the GL view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely in the openGL contexts. The thing is each of the controllers will create each own context and each must be set before used in any, the drawing, presenting, texture loading.

I never use such nonsense as the `GLKView` or the `GLKViewController` so bear with me. Either the issue is that the textures are loaded in only one context for which you either need to load them for each and every context (the view controller) or find a way to create a context with the share group from one of the controllers: When you create a context you can get a share group from it and then initialize the new context with this share group (a context property). The result is the new context may use the elements such as textures created on the primary context and vice versa. A bigger issue may be that these controllers are doing some additional work with the openGL and the context is not reset before doing so.

Anyway making multiple views using openGL should work just fine so I hope you find a nice solution for your issue. Maybe all you need to do is set the current context in the top of your `loadTextures` method.

Comment: This was the exact solution.  All I had to do was add `[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];` at the beginning of `loadTextures` THANK YOU!

Comment: Great. Still it feels bad that you need all the textures for each of the view controllers instead of a single pool of textures on a shared context. You could try to force the context itself: Create a context before any of the view controllers then manually set that context to each controller you create. If this works you should be able to lose most of the context setting and you can have an external texture pool.